# Why does Liza Daly's fast_iter use a while loop instead of an if statement?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm working on a project that requires processing large XML files. Using Python, I inevitably came across Liza Daly's article, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/. However, I don't understand the specifics of one line in her fast_iter function:

```
def fast_iter(context, func):
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context
```

Why use a while loop instead of an if statement? How could there be more than one previous element?

edit: I forgot to mention that I only saw an if version on one site that I can't read, anyway, http://jsome.net/blog/2010/08/18/handle-large-xml-with-python. It seems like almost everybody else uses fast_iter as is.

If I may ask one more related question...

For my project, I see that just adding elem.clear() reduces the memory footprint from 17+ GB to 60 MB. Further adding

```
while elem.getprevious() is not None:
    del elem.getparent()[0]
```

only reduces it to 40 MB. I haven't saved my context in a variable, so I haven't tried adding "del context" yet. Either way, both 60 MB and 40 MB are negligible to me. Is there a justification for me to still add the code in question?

```
    while elem.getprevious() is not None:
        del elem.getparent()[0]
del context
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first, because it seems more important:

Imagine you had a node with 10000 direct subtrees. Just doing the `elem.clear` wouldn't clean up the 10000 nodes at the top of those subtrees until the parent node was finished.

If you have only a handful of subtrees, this doesn't make much difference. (Even if the subtrees are very deep, each one gets `clear`ed as it goes along, so only the roots of each subtree are in existence., so the `del elem.getparent()[0]` isn't going to be that important. And it may even conceivably hurt performance more than it helps memory usage. So, if you know what kind of XML you're going to be processing, you probably want to test it both ways to see.

But if you have no idea what shape your code will be called on to deal with, it's probably worth deleting the previous siblings.

---

As for the first question:

I've never seen this blog post before, but I've written similar code in two projects in the past, and I've never used `while`. In fact, this seems clumsy to me in another way—you don't need to do this on both `start` and `end` events; just remove the previous child on `start`, or, even more simply, remove yourself on `end`, right?

But the blog post is presumably trying to be as general as possible. For one thing, `context` could be an `iterparse` that gives only `start` or only `end`, right? And meanwhile, `func` could be something that mutates the tree on the fly. I've got two projects that do mutate trees on the fly while `iterparse`-ing them—and, while neither of them would actually need this loop, that's only because one of them happens to insert after rather than before.

As user1093967 pointed out, the lxml docs section [Modifying the tree](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#modifying-the-tree) explains a scenario where you might want to use the `while` instead of the `if`: If you expand the code to filter the search, you could you could have multiple siblings that you've skipped over.

Anyway, unlike the previous case, there's no real cost here in using `while` instead of `if`, or in checking on both `start` and `end`, so you might as well stick with the fully general solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to the second part. I do have a root node with a very large number of subtrees that I'm iterating over, so that makes sense. I should have realized that the cost of an empty Element is still significant.

Sorry, I should have been more specific about my use case. I'm only using end events, although I have also seen the example on http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm, which enables start events to clear root. I guess that means I could just remove each node after processing it, but I also see your point about keeping the more generic code.

Comment: http://lxml.de/parsing.html#modifying-the-tree offers an explanation as to the while-versus-if dilemma.

Comment: @user1093967: Thanks! I'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: @user1093967: If you're writing a function to be used in multiple different projects—or an article to be used by many different readers—you have to make the code generic. If you're just doing a one-shot project, if it's simpler or more efficient to avoid being fully general, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily find out for yourself by adding a `print elem.getprevious() is not None` in the loop and seeing if you get more than one `True` per node.

However, even if in your application the `while` loop isn't necessary, it's possible that `func()` could add nodes, so... better safe than sorry. For the same reason, I assume, she's calling `getparent()` each time through the loop instead of storing the parent before entering the loop and merely referencing it in the body of the loop, which would be faster... `func()` could change the parent, in theory.

If the extra memory isn't a problem I wouldn't bother. Executing more Python code is slower than executing less.

By the way, assuming the `Element` class has similar storage characteristics to a Python list, deleting the *first* child element each time through the loop probably could be sub-optimal from a performance standpoint. Whether you'd notice would depend on your document, but it might be slightly faster to iterate over them in reverse order and delete next nodes rather than the previous ones, assuming order doesn't matter (or can easily be corrected afterward).

Comment: From the question, the first change "reduces the memory footprint from 17+ GB to 60 MB". On most machines, that extra 17GB means lots of time wasted in swap thrashing, etc., which will affect performance a lot worse than running a bit of extra Python code… But you still make a good point that, like any optimization, this isn't something to apply blindly—you need to know your own running characteristics before you can know what to improve.